# I got an error when downloading an image with picasso library, android

Tags: android, image, picasso

[image]when i run this code in the oncreate method :

```
Picasso.with(this).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(image);
```

I got these errors:

- 03-11 20:02:47.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1577): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
- 03-11 20:02:47.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1577): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
- 03-11 20:02:47.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):   at com.example.news.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:45)
- 03-11 20:02:47.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
- 03-11 20:02:47.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
- 03-11 20:02:47.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
- 03-11 20:02:47.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
- 03-11 20:02:47.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
- 03-11 20:02:47.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
- 03-11 20:02:47.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
- 03-11 20:02:47.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
- 03-11 20:02:47.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
- 03-11 20:02:47.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
- 03-11 20:02:47.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
- 03-11 20:02:47.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
- 03-11 20:02:47.240: E/AndroidRuntime(1577):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

please help me !

Comment: Are you using Eclipse?

Comment: yes i am using eclipse

Comment: Is this library marked as exported in Eclipse?

Comment: In what folder did you put it?

Comment: no, actually i download it to eclipse with build path

Comment: it don't put it in any folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you put it in `libs` folder and Eclipse will pack it properly for you.

Either you leave it as it is, but go to project properties, Export tab and check the library. This way Eclipse will pack it in the final APK.

Comment: please see the image that i upload to my question

Comment: Move picasso jar file in `libs` folder ... just as I have proposed